# How to refer DNS queries to another NS?

Tags: bind, nameserver, dns-server, domain-name-system

A domain of mine, `example.com`, is handled by NS `server1` (as configured in the domain registrar).
But now I want it to be handled by a different NS, say `server2`, without changing the NS in the domain registrar.

In other words:
`server1` is a NS with a DNS zone for `example.com`
`server2` is also a NS with a DNS zone for `example.com`

The registered NS for the domain `example.com` is `server1`.

Is it possible to configure in some way the DNS zone in `server1` so that DNS clients are referred to `server2`?

PS:
Why do I want to avoid changing the NS in the domain registrar?
Because doing the change in the registrar is not instantaneous (aside from propagation).
Because they ask too much confirmations.
Because the actual change has to be done by another person in charge of the domain.
Because we are transitioning from one hosting to another and we will be going back and forth for some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reasonable answer is "No, you should just update the delegation".

When changing nameservers the delegation needs to change, anything else will be a temporary workaround at best.

Do remember to update both the authoritative and delegation data. Ie, both the delegatory `NS` and glue `A`/`AAAA` (as applicable) in the parent zone as well as your own authoritative `NS` and `A`/`AAAA` (as applicable).

As for your listed disadvantages, I think these are largely overcome by careful planning on your part. (As an example, I'd like to think that you can avoid switching back and forth between different nameservers.)

Comment: If I only have a primary zone, how can I change the delegation without changing the NS in the domain registrar?

Comment: @GetFree You can't.